Are hyperplanes Upper and Lower semicontinous correspondence?
Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^2 \to P(\mathbb{R}^2)$ where $P(⋅)$
is a power set, defined by $ \Phi(d) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^2: d^T x =0\}$
where $d^T$
is the transpose of vector $d$. So, it is clear that for a given $d\in\mathbb{R}^2$
, the map $\Phi$
takes $d$
to a hyperplane passing through origin with normal as $d$.
Question: Is the map $\Phi$
usc or lsc correspondence? Definition of usc and lsc are here

I am not able to imagine the open set which contains the hyperplane (in codomain set) and construct an open set in domain set $\mathbb{R}^2$
that satisfies the usc or lsc conditions.
